How to find file location for packages installed by tlmgr_install
I'm new to Latex and rMarkdown, so apologies if this is a very basic question. I'm having trouble finding the file location for the packages installed by tinytex::tlmgr_install. Where can I find the location of these packages?
For example, where can I find the file locations for the packages "longtable" and "rotating" installed via the code below?
library("tinytex")
tinytex::tlmgr_install("longtable")
tinytex::tlmgr_install("rotating")

My operating system is Mac OS 12.5. I have tried searching for the package names in Finder but did not hit any results. I believe these packages did install successfully because I am able to use them to reproduce examples in rmarkdown from the xtable tutorial, such as:
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)
x.big <- xtable(x, caption = "My Table")
print(x.big, hline.after=c(-1, 0), tabular.environment = "longtable")


You'll probably find them under ls ~/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/.
For example, here are my LaTeX packages:
% ls ~/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex
academicons euenc       graphics-def    lineno      times
amscls      fancyhdr    helvetic    lm      tipa
amsfonts    fancyvrb    hycolor     mdwtools    tools
amsmath     filehook    hyperref    microtype   unicode-math
arydshln    firstaid    ifplatform  minted      upquote
atveryend   float       inconsolata multirow    url
auxhook     fontawesome5    kvoptions   natbib      xcolor
base        fontspec    kvsetkeys   newfloat    xkeyval
bookmark    framed      l3backend   psnfss      zapfding
booktabs    fvextra     l3kernel    refcount
colortbl    geometry    l3packages  rerunfilecheck
epstopdf-pkg    graphics    latexconfig symbol
etoolbox    graphics-cfg    letltxmacro tex-ini-files


You could check with the system function where file path is of the installed packages. Using the kpsewich command like discussed here, you can find the path of the TEXMF packages like this:
system("kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME", intern = TRUE)
#> [1] "/Users/quinten/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-local"

Created on 2024-05-08 with reprex v2.1.0
